# Using variables within Apache virtualhost containers

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

If request is coming from http://xxx.domain.com,

i want to be able to say;

DocumentRoot /home/${SUBDOMAIN_NAME}

so that Virtual host's DocumentRoot will be assigned to /home/xxx

Any way I can accomplish this?

Thanks,
D

ps: please don't worry about security or how bad this idea is. I have over-simplified the problem for the sake of simplicity.

Real usage will be as follows:

```
<IfModule mpm_itk_module> AssignUserId ${SUBDOMAIN_NAME} usergroup </IfModule>
```

There will be a unix user with the corresponding subdomain name.

Comment: I will also accept "no you can't" as an answer if you don't mind explaining why.

Comment: I know all these variables are set at the time when apache reloads ( so there is no request coming in at the time of restart), but sometimes there are workarounds (such as http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/vhosts/mass.html) I'm hoping maybe there is something for us as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is provided by Jeff.

[Using URL within Vhost container with mod_perl dynamically](https://serverfault.com/questions/85256/using-url-within-vhost-container-with-modperl-dynamically)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is mass virtual hosting:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/vhosts/mass.html

Or http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html

You probably want something like:

```
UseCanonicalName    Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /home/%-1
```

%-1 would get the subdomain.

Read the sites listed for more information.

Comment: Hi Nathan, I thought this would work great but here is what i get:

apache2: bad user name %-1
   ...fail!

I'm using it inside:

<IfModule mpm_itk_module>                                                                                                         
           AssignUserId %-1 usergroup                                                                                                               
        </IfModule>

Comment: ${%-1} didn't work either.

Comment: The % syntax only works with VirtualDocumentRoot. You won't be able to plug % into any other parameter.

Answer (score -1):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName xxx.example.com
DocumentRoot /www/xxx
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName yyy.example.com
DocumentRoot /www/yyy
</VirtualHost>
```

---

above is a simple example of name-based...you can also use ip based:

```
<VirtualHost xxx.example.com>
ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
DocumentRoot /groups/example/xxx
ServerName xxx.example.com
ErrorLog /groups/example_xxx/logs/error_log
TransferLog /groups/example_xxxx/logs/access_log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost yyy.example.com>
ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
DocumentRoot /groups/example/yyy
ServerName yyy.example.com
ErrorLog /groups/example_yyy/logs/error_log
TransferLog /groups/example_yyy/logs/access_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: this isn't an answer to what i asked. thanks though.

Comment: sorry...i must've misunderstood the question.